# Open IE in private mode using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, automation, private

I want to open IE browser in private mode to run the set of automated test cases using Selenium webdriver c#.

I have used the below option to open the browser in private mode.

```
BrowserCommandLineArguments = "private",
ForceCreateProcessApi = true,
```

but it shows the following error

```
Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Unable to use CreateProcess() API. To use CreateProcess() with Internet Explorer 8 or higher, the value of registry setting in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth must be '0'..
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to test the code on Win 10 with the IE 11 browser and found that the code is working fine.

```
            InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
            {
                ForceCreateProcessApi = true,
                BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private",
            };
            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"IE_driver_path_here...",options);
           
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://Your_URL_here...");
```

Output in the IE 11:

[image]

From the error message, it looks like the value of the `TabProcGrowth` key in the registry is not 0 which is causing this error.

Please refer to the steps below.

1. Launch the Registry editor.
2. Browse to the path below.

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main`

3. Find the `TabProcGrowth` key and double click on it.
4. Set its value to 0 and click on the OK button.

[image]

Then, again try to run the code.

Comment: I have added those lines in my code and also updated new Registry value. It shows new  error.

 The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver timed out after 60 seconds


Let me know why this is happening

Comment: Deepak if you know, please help on this. it will be great help for me

Comment: Also the browser is not launching.

Comment: I have used your same mentioned code and I have updated a TabProcGrowth value too.
I am facing new error. 

The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver timed out after 60 seconds .

Also the browser is not  launching for me. May I know why.

Comment: From your last comment, I can see that error you had posted in the original post is solved by updating the registry value and now you are getting a new error. I noticed that you had created a new [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66226119/ie-in-private-mode-using-selenium-c-sharp) for that specific error. As the original error is solved for this thread, I would suggest you accept the helpful suggestion as an answer for this thread and we can discuss the new error on your other thread. [please see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks for your understanding.