# IE in Private Mode using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, private

I want to open IE in Private mode to run the set of test cases. The browser is not opening. It shows error as

```
The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL {URL} timed out after 60 seconds
```

Sample code:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
{
    ForceCreateProcessApi = true,
    BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private",
};
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver("C:\\Reports", options);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Also I have changed the TabProcGrowth as 0 in Registry Editor.

How to open IE in private mode to run the test case? Anything I want to update in my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add `PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager` to the `options` and again try to run your code. See whether it makes any difference. If the issue still persists, I suggest you inform us which exact version of the IE browser, web driver, and selenium you are using for making this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I manage to launch it:

1. Set the TabProcGrowth as 0 in Registry Editor.
2. Get the Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver64 nugget instead of the normal 32 and build the project
3. Get the IEDriverServer64.exe from bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1 (the output folder where this file is generated depends on your TargetFramework: .netcore or .netstandard)
4. Rename that file into IEDriverServer.exe and put it somewhere in a folder
5. Create the driver instance using the path to that folder. In my case, I created a folder in the project and pointed there

[Project: Solution Explorer View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51ula.png)

```html
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using System.IO;

namespace InternetExplorerPrivate
{
    public class Tests
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
            options.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;
            options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
            options.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private";
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\..\IEDriver"), options); 
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works perfect now. Great.. Thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot.

Comment: If you know answer for my next question. Please let me know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238850/how-to-set-a-relative-path-in-c-sharp-selenium-for-ie-driver