# How to set a relative path in C# selenium for IE driver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, path, relative-path

In the below code, IEDriverServer.exe is available in my local machine. I want to run this code in different machines. How to set a relative path while getting IEDriverServer.exe in C#.

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
            {
                ForceCreateProcessApi = true,
                BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private",
                IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
                IgnoreZoomLevel = true
                
            };
            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(Path.GetFullPath("C:\\Users\\kamal\\Documents\\Sample\\Sample\\bin\\Debug"), options);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");

            driver.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path to the file is C:\Users\kamal\Documents\Sample\Sample\bin\Debug\IEDriverServer.exe

The relative path to that is:

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\"), options);
```

If its C:\Users\kamal\Documents\Sample\Sample\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\IEDriverServer.exe

you can use `driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(".", options);`

More detailed the paths are like this:

```
var projectRoot = Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\..\"); //which in your case is C:\\Users\\kamal\\Documents\\Sample\\Sample\\
var projectRootBin = Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\"); // C:\\Users\\kamal\\Documents\\Sample\\Sample\\bin
var projectRootBinDebug = Path.GetFullPath(@"..\"); // C:\\Users\\kamal\\Documents\\Sample\\Sample\\bin\Debug
var projectRootBinDebugNetCoreApp31 = Path.GetFullPath("."); // C:\\Users\\kamal\\Documents\\Sample\\Sample\\bin\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1
```